# What happens when Files.move() fails?

Tags: java

As the title suggests, I wonder if the existing target file could be changed or not if `Files.move(src,target ,REPLACE_EXISTING)` fails? Would the target file only be totally overwritten if `move()` succeeds or the target file could be partially overwritten even when `move()` fails.

Comment: It's safer to do a file copy, followed by a file delete.

Comment: @Gilbert Wouldn't that depend? For instance, if the target is on the same drive then isn't the pointer (or whatever you call it) simply changed and no transfer of data actually occurs? Doing a copy-then-delete operation would be more costly and increase the chance of errors in that case, wouldn't it?

Comment: @Slaw, that makes sense. But not really sure how move() actually works and didn't find any document talking about the details.

Comment: Many aspects of the `java.nio.file` API are left unspecified since it has to remain as abstract as possible. It can't get more detailed because not every file system behaves exactly the same way. Not to mention the `FileSystem[Provider]` implementation doesn't have to interact with a "real", native file system; for instance, there's the _ZIP FileSystemProvider_, which allows accessing ZIP files as if they were a file system, and also https://github.com/google/jimfs, which keeps everything entirely within memory.

Comment: Although the implementation will be different for each platform, the Windows implementation is in [`WindowsFileCopy#move`](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/master/src/java.base/windows/classes/sun/nio/fs/WindowsFileCopy.java#L266), which eventually calls [this native method](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/master/src/java.base/windows/native/libnio/fs/WindowsNativeDispatcher.c#L446), which ultimately calls [MoveFileExW](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-movefileexw) from the win32 API. These are implementation details, however.

Answer (score 3):

I just found the answer [in the JavaDocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#copy-java.nio.file.Path-java.nio.file.Path-java.nio.file.CopyOption...-).

> When the move is performed as a non-atomic operation, and an `IOException` is thrown, then the state of the files is not defined. The original file and the target file may both exist, the target file may be incomplete or some of its file attributes may not been copied from the original file